# Perl is respecting '<' as a regular character rather an output redirection

Tags: perl

I would like some help figuring this particular coding problem.

I have a perl script (#1) that calls another perl script(#2). In #1, I call #2 to also redirect its output to a log file. like so

```
my @command = ('downloadImage', '-url', $url, '>', $log);
```

this commands runs fine when it runs on the terminal. 
Do I have to use some other kind of special character to tell perl that > is output redirection not just some regular character?

I run it as:

```
system(@command);
```

Comment: How are you executing `@command`?

Answer (score 4):

I assume the full code is:

```
my @command = ('downloadImage', '-url', $url, '>', $log);
system @command;
```

`system` has two modes. `system $command` will run `$command` in the shell.

```
# This will write 'foo' to the file 'bar'
system "echo foo > bar";
```

`system @command` is really `system $program, @args`. It will bypass the shell and run the `$program` with `@args`.

```
# This will print 'foo > bar'
system "echo", "foo", ">", "bar"
```

So if you want to do output redirection like that you could join @command together.

```
system join " ", @command;
```

But that can run into shell quoting issues. It's safer, faster, and more portable to do the redirection yourself in Perl using a [piped open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $echo, "-|", "echo", "foo";
open my $log, ">", "some.log";

print {$log} <$echo>;
```

Comment: Tip: `print {$log} $_ while <$echo>;` reduces the memory overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Doing

```
system('downloadImage', '-url', $url, '>', $log)
```

in Perl is the same as doing

```
'downloadImage' '-url' "$url" '>' "$log"
```

in the shell. This executes `downloadImage` with four arguments, one of which is `>`. The shell command you were trying to execute is the following:

```
'downloadImage' '-url' "$url" > "$log"
```

If you want to execute that shell command, you first need a shell. The following is how you should achieve this:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my @cmd = ('downloadImage', '-url', $url);

my $shell_cmd = shell_quote(@cmd) . ' >' . shell_quote($log);
system($shell_cmd);  # Short for system('/bin/sh', '-c', $shell_cmd);
```

---

However, there are lots of downsides to using a shell. Here are some alternatives:

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

my @cmd = ('downloadImage', '-url', $url);

{
   open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null')
      or die("Can't open \"/dev/null\": $!\n");

   open(local *CHILD_STDOUT, '>', $log)
      or die("Can't create \"$log\": $!\n");

   my $pid = open3('<&CHILD_STDIN', '>&CHILD_STDOUT', '>&STDERR', @cmd);
   waitpid($pid, 0);
}
```

or

```
use IPC::Run3 qw( run3 );

my @cmd = ('downloadImage', '-url', $url);

run3(\@cmd, \undef, $log);
```

or

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );

my @cmd = ('downloadImage', '-url', $url);

run(\@cmd, '<', '/dev/null', '>', $log);
```

Comment: (I only included IPC::Open3 because it's bundled with Perl. It's honestly too low-level for most uses.)